# iPhone App Crash - Error?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Im new im making in making iPhone apps so i have no idea what this error means ?

I saw another post with this error but i couldn't figure out how to get it right..

i get this error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for
the key ImageView.'**

and i have no clue what this means ? 0.o

can some help me here ?

Thanks!

Comment: When this crash happens? Does debugger stop on specific line?

Comment: nothing happens when i debug.. its dosent stop the debug at the error, it just go through and exit the app right when it was supposed to start up.. i have checked my nib file and think everything is in order, but sine im new with this i im sure ofc.

Comment: Do you have a class with a property of "ImageView"? If you could post the property definitions that may help.

Comment: Hmm dunno ? :/ inside the ViewController i made an Outlets canned ImageView with type UIImageView but i cant find that one anywhere ? but i linked the ImageView to my File's Owner.. if u know what i mean ?

Comment: dunno if this helps ?
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iStreamViewController *viewController;

Thats the only to i have in "AppDelegate", if that dosent help, where shall i look in my code or classes for this error ? sorry if i dont understand, im just so new in this

Comment: Yeah, that helps. What is "iStreamViewController"? If that is one of your classes, can you post its properties, too?

Answer (score 1):

Check your nib to see if you have an outlet or action hooked up to a property that no longer exists in the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You might have changed the name of the IBOutlet your nib file refers to.

1. Check each connection in your nib file to see what it references
2. Search in your code for that reference to confirm it's there.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue after deleting an object I created in Interface Builder. Deleting the object did not erase all of the code artifacts it had produced.

Here is how I removed the unwanted information in XCode 4.3:

1. **Ctrl + Click** the interface builder file, **Open As -> Source Code**
2. Press **Cmd + F** to search for **"*imageView*"**
3. **Delete** the corresponding **XML element**. For example, you might erase this entire block of text:

   `<outlet property="imageView" destination="9W1-Bu-YFJ" id="9xu-Y0-uYk"/>`
4. **Repeat** steps 2-3 as necessary

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the @synthesize for imageView.